# Multi-Section Grid Layout

Tags: css, css-grid

https://codepen.io/dye/pen/LyRJym

In this layout, I want to have a sort of divider between 2 sections of a grid layout. The number of items in either section are unknown and dynamic. What's the best way to go about this? I've added a divider that I want to start at the first column line and end at the last column line. However, I don't know how to select the last line.

Currently, I have

```
.grid-item--divider {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}
```

This looks great when the browser is sized to display 4 columns. But when the browser is resized and the the number of columns are increased/decreased, the layout breaks. How can I always select the last column line? Or is there a better practice for accomplishing this that doesn't involve using a divider?

*Note: My previous approach was to have 2 grid containers, one for each section. But because of the dynamic nature of the layout, the columns of both section would not necessarily line up. Ideally, I want the columns to match even if, e.g., one section only had one item while the other section had many items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just use flexboxes:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Not sure flex can handle colums and rows matching together :( it's a typical grid here

Comment: not here , the grid system is set at 250px mini-width and a divider is there. rows can be filled with various numbers of item :)  forked and modified a bit 3rd example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PmGyEb

Answer (score 0):

You will need either a javascript to sort how many columns you have to span or use mediaqueries:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item--divider {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;/* fine for  1820px - 2080px */
  border: solid;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 250px;/* eventually */
}
/* breaking points */

@media all and (max-width: 1820px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 7;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1560px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 6;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1290px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 5;
  }
}@media all and (max-width: 1030px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 770px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
   }
}
@media all and (max-width: 510px) {
  .grid-item--divider {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--top">Item 7</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--divider"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--bottom">Item 8</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--bottom">Item 9</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--bottom">Item 10</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--bottom">Item 11</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--bottom">Item 12</div>
</div>
```